# Чтобы блок display: flex не вылезал за границы родительского блока при растягивании его содержимого

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, позиционирование

Видео плеер находится внутри блока div(.relatVid) с помощью которого на видео позиционируются элементы управления и прочее. Нужно вписать блок div(.relatVid) в div(.videBlock) так, чтобы он растягивался по вертикали и горизонтали по размерам вложенного видео. Но иногда видео с большой высотой растягивают блок div(.relatVid) настолько что он выходит(по вертикали) за пределы родительского div(.videBlock). В этом случае нужно чтобы div вместе с содержимым уменьшался по горизонтали сохраняя пропорции - чтобы никогда не вылезал за пределы div(.videBlock). Как этого добиться?

В общем чтобы div растягивался по содержимому сохраняя пропорции, но никогда не вылазил за пределы родительского?

```css
.videBlock {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}

.relatVid {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.relatVid>video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="videBlock">
  <div class="relatVid">
    <video class="myVideo" id="myVideo" controls="controls" src="" poster=""> 
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уберите у родителя `height: 0;` и `padding-bottom` задайте не в процентах, если я правильно понял, чего вы хотите.

Comment: @Quazimorda А если нужно ограничить родителя по высоте при всем этом скажем max-height: 500px? Потому что уж очень сильно начал родитель растягиваться. А если так и написать max-height: 500px, то часть видео не видна за его нижней границей просто а не уменьшается div(.relatVid). Кстати как padding-bottom на это все влиял не пойму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется ограничить родительский элемент какой-то высотой, как у вас указано в комментарии, то можно, например, написать так:

```css
.videBlock {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.relatVid {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.relatVid > video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  object-fit: contain;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="videBlock">
  <div class="relatVid">
    <video class="myVideo" id="myVideo" controls="controls" src="" poster="">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть, у селекторов `.videBlock` и `.relatVid > video` указываю `max-height: 500px;`, убираю лишнее, добавляю родителю цвет фона и padding для наглядности. Кроме того, у родителя прописываю явно `overflow-y: hidden;`. Этого должно быть достаточно.

Другое дело, что растягивать видео на 100% и по ширине, и по высоте - не есть хорошо. Так как сильно могут растянуться пропорции.